# .NET Grid using paging - search and scroll to result

Tags: asp.net, search, grid

I have an ASP .NET web application.  I'm fairly new to .Net but a longtime SQL and Java programmer.  I have a requirement to implement a search feature as it is currently implemented in the legacy application.  There is a pageable grid of data displayed and a search box.  You type your search criteria and the grid pages to the first match.  A "next match" button pages to the next item etc.  This way the user sees where their search item falls in the hierarchy of the data.  I have seen examples where the search criteria filters the data, limiting the data results.  This is not what I need.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for this?  Is it possible with .NET?

I have some crazy custom ideas but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Edit - To clarify, is there an existing .Net control or functionality that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You said this was an existing application and that you normally write Java, so I would presume the existing app is written in Java. Java and C# are very similar, so you could almost write the one side by side from the other.

As for the logic of how to do this, how does the *existing* app do it? Why reinvent the wheel? You've only been asked to recode the logic into a new platform. Don't give up the years of experience the existing solution provides.

Comment: Thanks.  The java version uses a custom control which works differently than the Grid View control in .Net.  This Grid View is also a requirement.

Comment: Ok, so I'm still lost. Paging usually involves finding a chunk of information to show based on inputs from the user || default inputs. Displaying the information is usually fairly static. The paging control can be rewritten from Java no? I've written at least two custom pagers for ASP.NET now, the first one being a throwaway to demonstrate to my colleagues.

Comment: I have a grid view that connects to s SQL query which returns 500 results.  The grid displays 25 at a time.  The user clicks next and page 2 displays and so on.  This is built into the grid view.  I need to be able to have the user enter a value and have the grid reload to the correct page and highlight the first matched row.  I have not seen this ability in any demos that I've seen.

Comment: Ooooh, well that IS a workable feature, you need to use an ObjectDataSource (or one of the sister-types to that). It'll do in-memory caching on the IIS box, but it's negligible and IIS knows how to flush them to keep them from piling up. As for the "find the next occurrence and page to that row" that's custom and you'll have to write that no matter what. But the "give a GridView 500 rows and tell it to page 25 at a time" is done for you.